How do I show only years on flowbite datepicker
I want the user to select only the year from flowbite-datepicker
But I don't know how do that. I tried to add the datepicker-format attribute with the value yyyy like this:
<div id="date-range-picker" date-rangepicker datepicker-format="yyyy"
class="w-full flex items-center">

but it is still show me the full calender, when a date selected it takes the year only.

It doesn't look like having a year-selection ONLY is even a possible option with that date picker. I'm not sure why you believe it would be

@RoryMcCrossan Why wouldn't I believe it? other libraries have this feature, like material ui, plus it stores the value on input type text so any value can be there

@RoryMcCrossan Do u know any other datepicker that have this feature? even if it a jQuery plugins I don't mind,

Sure other libraries have it. That one clearly doesn't. It's not like changing a setting is going to add some custom behaviour that the library does not support. I don't know of any other libraries that have this off the top of my head. However if all you need is to select a year, why over complicate it? Use a select dropdown with whatever styling you need.

flowbite-datepicker is a fork from the vanillajs-datepicker .
I just had to add the pick level option provided on the vanillajs-datepicker docs:
const dateRangePickerEl = document.getElementById("date-range-picker");
    new DateRangePicker(dateRangePickerEl, {
        pickLevel: 2,
    });


The level that the date picker allows to pick. 0:date,1: month or 2:year.
checkout this documentation
